# Multi-tenant application new version migration

Tags: azure, multi-tenant, azure-cloud-services

We are developing a multi tenant web application on Azure. When we release a new version we want to deploy it to a new server and gradually migrate clients from the old to the new version.

We don't want the URL to change for our clients. Instead we want to look them up in our user table and redirect them to the appropriate server based on what version they are set to.

What is the best way to do this?

It seems we need at least 3 servers: a server to receive requests and look up the user, a server running the new version and server/s running the old version/s. Is this the right model? Are there any tools that do this already? Will the servers scale?

We are using Azure Cloud Services, not Azure Websites.

Answer (score 0):

Azure allows you to upload a Cloud Services package(.cspkg) to a staging area so you can release your new version there without disrupting current production. If your application is stateless you can swap prod and staging instances and users will be none the wiser.

You can find out more here:http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-how-to-manage/